# How to: Save order of tabs when customizing tabs in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am having problems finding any other information than the docs for how to save the tab order for my UITabBarController, so that the user's customization is saved for next app launch. I have searched online, but have been unable to find any blog posts or articles that goes through the proper code for doing this.

I realize I have to use the delegate methods for the UITabBarController (didEndCustomizingViewControllers:) but I am not sure how I best approach persistance in terms of saving the state of the order the user wants the tabs in.

Can someone post some code, point me in the right direction or perhaps you have a link for something saved? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as you've asked for some sample code I will simply post here how I dealt with the same task in my app.

Quick intro: I was using a NIB file for storing initial `UITabBarController` state and to differ my tabs one from another I simply defined tag variables for `UITabBarItem` objects assigned to each `UIViewController` stuffed in my `UITabBarController`. To be able to accurately track last selected tab (including the 'More' one) I've implemented following methods for `UITabBarControllerDelegate` of my `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate` of its moreNavigationController. Here they are:

```
#pragma mark UINavigationControllerDelegate

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:mainTabBarController.selectedIndex forKey:@"mainTabBarControllerSelectedIndex"];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:mainTabBarController.selectedIndex forKey:@"mainTabBarControllerSelectedIndex"];
}

#pragma mark UITabBarControllerDelegate

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:tabBarController.selectedIndex forKey:@"mainTabBarControllerSelectedIndex"];
}
```

And here's the code for saving the tabs order:

```
#pragma mark UITabBarControllerDelegate

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didEndCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers changed:(BOOL)changed {
    int count = mainTabBarController.viewControllers.count;
    NSMutableArray *savedTabsOrderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
        [savedTabsOrderArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[mainTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] tabBarItem] tag]]];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:savedTabsOrderArray] forKey:@"tabBarTabsOrder"];
    [savedTabsOrderArray release];
}
```

As you can see I've been storing the order of tabs' indexes in an array in `NSUserDefaults`.

On app's launch in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method I reordered the `UIViewControllers` using following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    mainTabBarController.delegate = self;

    int count = mainTabBarController.viewControllers.count;
    NSArray *savedTabsOrderArray = [[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"tabBarTabsOrder"] retain];
    if (savedTabsOrderArray.count == count) {
        BOOL needsReordering = NO;

        NSMutableDictionary *tabsOrderDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
            NSNumber *tag = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[[mainTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] tabBarItem] tag]];
            [tabsOrderDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:[tag stringValue]];

        if (!needsReordering && ![(NSNumber *)[savedTabsOrderArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToNumber:tag]) {
                needsReordering = YES;
            }
        }

        if (needsReordering) {
            NSMutableArray *tabsViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
                [tabsViewControllers addObject:[mainTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:
                                                [(NSNumber *)[tabsOrderDictionary objectForKey:
                                                              [(NSNumber *)[savedTabsOrderArray objectAtIndex:i] stringValue]] intValue]]];
            }
            [tabsOrderDictionary release];

            mainTabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tabsViewControllers];
            [tabsViewControllers release];
        }
    }
    [savedTabsOrderArray release];

    if ([userDefaults integerForKey:@"mainTabBarControllerSelectedIndex"]) {
        if ([userDefaults integerForKey:@"mainTabBarControllerSelectedIndex"] == 2147483647) {
            mainTabBarController.selectedViewController = mainTabBarController.moreNavigationController;
        }
        else {
            mainTabBarController.selectedIndex = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"mainTabBarControllerSelectedIndex"];
        }
    }

    mainTabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;

    [window addSubview:mainTabBarController.view];
}
```

It's quite tricky and may seem strange, but don't forget that my `UITabBarController` was fully created in a nib file. If you construct it programmatically you may simply do the same but following the saved order.

P.S.: and don't forget to synchronize `NSUserDefaults` when your app terminates.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

I hope this will help. If something is not clear please do comment and ask.

Comment: Hi Iva, thanks for posting the above. I was just wondering if you could elaborate on the actual loop you run to create the array you save in your NSUSerDefaults for the tab order? Because I realize it's possible to get the view controller's index, but I assume this just gives me the order it's in now, and not how it should be - and how this fits with creating them next time. Do you alloc the view controllers with a tag or how would I know which one is which?

Comment: I actually posted all the code from the very beginning, the reason why it wasn't displayed properly is because I've totally missed that '<' character interrupts 'code' and 'pre' tags... Changed them to &lt; and now everything looks OK.

Comment: Ah, thanks :) But it looks like some of it is still missing from the didEndCustomizingViewControllers: method..

Comment: Yes it is... ;(
I don't know why I started writing code and pre tags instead of simply using this gorgeous WYSIWYG function. :-x
Fixed everything now (hopefully)!

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH, Ivan. Your code is amazing. I pretty just had to copy and paste it and it worked! App now restores the tabs in the right order AND launches in the tab last selected. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU :)

Comment: It worked right ahead because I've actually taken it directly from my app GlobeMaster, which is already in the App Store. ;)
You're welcome!

Comment: Hehe. Well, just saying, I didn't have to change much to make it work with mine. I haven't used IB, btw.

Comment: Wouldnt it be possible to save the whole object directly ? or maybe thats an overkill?

Answer (score 16):

First I voted up the previous answer, but then I noticed how ridiculously complex it is. It can and should be simplified.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSArray *initialViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
    NSArray *tabBarOrder = [[AppDelegate sharedSettingsService] tabBarOrder];
    if (tabBarOrder) {
        NSMutableArray *newViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:initialViewControllers.count];
        for (NSNumber *tabBarNumber in tabBarOrder) {
            NSUInteger tabBarIndex = [tabBarNumber unsignedIntegerValue];
            [newViewControllers addObject:[initialViewControllers objectAtIndex:tabBarIndex]];
        }
        self.tabBarController.viewControllers = newViewControllers;
    }

    NSInteger tabBarSelectedIndex = [[AppDelegate sharedSettingsService] tabBarSelectedIndex];
    if (NSIntegerMax == tabBarSelectedIndex) {
        self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController;
    } else {
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = tabBarSelectedIndex;
    }

    /* Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window. */
    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSInteger tabBarSelectedIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
    [[AppDelegate sharedSettingsService] setTabBarSelectedIndex:tabBarSelectedIndex];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didEndCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers changed:(BOOL)changed {

        NSUInteger count = tabBarController.viewControllers.count;
        NSMutableArray *tabOrderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];
        for (UIViewController *viewController in viewControllers) {

            NSInteger tag = viewController.tabBarItem.tag;
            [tabOrderArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:tag]];
        }

        [[AppDelegate sharedSettingsService] setTabBarOrder:[NSArray arrayWithArray:tabOrderArray]];
        [tabOrderArray release];
    }
```

All this happens in AppDelegate. You set UITabBarController's delegate to AppDelegate instance in Interface Builder. sharedSettingsService is what persists the data for me. Basically it can be a NSUserDefaults front-end or anything you like (CoreData for example). So everything is simple, Interface Builder helps here, not makes things more complex.

Comment: Never thought that reordering view controllers even when it's not needed and writing code using a little bit different syntax makes 'ridiculous' off-the-shelf solution 'simpler'. I'm glad I've helped you to saved some time by not implementing everything from scratch though.

Comment: Don't mislead my language, please. Ridiculous and ridiculously complex are different things.

Comment: Count is not a property on NSArray. That should be [tabBarController.viewControllers count].

Comment: Upped one ... This solution is definitely simpler ... no offense Ivan :)

Comment: Good job,simpler,and userful.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps late to the game, but been learning Swift for less than two months at school and sat perhaps more than fifteen hours with this because I couldn't find a decent explanation on the interwebz.

#### Here is a solution in Swift

1. Give all your tabItem's a tag, starting at 1. You do this in each separate view. If you got six views, their tabItems will in that case have a unique number each ranging between 1 and 6.
2. Add *UITabBarControllerDelegate* to all the ViewControllers' classes so you can use the function explained later in point 5.

   ```
   class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
   ```
3. Add the following **variable globally** (right after the code above, as an example) so you can save variables locally on the phone from any function within the class.

   ```
   let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
   ```
4. Delegate the tabBarController to the view so the view can update any changes to the tabBarController. Put the following into your *viewDidLoad()*.

   ```
   tabBarController!.delegate = self
   ```
5. Implement the following code. This one will activate when the user is editing the tab view. What the code does is taking the *[ViewControllers]*'s tags in the order they are in (after the user changed it) and saves it locally on the phone. The first  viewController's tag is saved as an integer in the variable "0", the second tag in a variable called "1", and so on.

   ```
   func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didEndCustomizingViewControllers viewControllers: [UIViewController], changed: Bool) {
       if (changed) {
           print("New tab order:")
           for (var i=0; i<viewControllers.count; i++) {
               defaults.setInteger(viewControllers[i].tabBarItem.tag, forKey: String(i))
               print("\(i): \(viewControllers[i].tabBarItem.title!) (\(viewControllers[i].tabBarItem.tag))")
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The prints tell you the new order of the tabs. Nothing you will need, but I think it's nice to see what's happening in the background. All this was only to save the order of the tabs. You will now have to retrieve them when the program is starting.

6. Switch from your *UIViewControl file* to *AppDelegate.swift*.
7. Finally, write the following in *func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*... that you can find at the top of *AppDelegate.swift*.

   ```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
   // Let you read and write to local variables on your phone
   let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

   // Getting access to your tabBarController
   let tabBar: UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

   var junkViewControllers = [UIViewController]()

   // returns 0 if not set, hence having the tabItem's tags starting at 1.
   var tagNumber : Int = defaults.integerForKey("0")

   if (tagNumber != 0) {
       for (var i=0; i<tabBar.viewControllers?.count; i++) {
           // the tags are between 1-6 but the order of the
           // viewControllers in the array are between 0-5
           // hence the "-1" below.
           tagNumber = defaults.integerForKey( String(i) ) - 1
           junkViewControllers.append(tabBar.viewControllers![tagNumber])
       }

       tabBar.viewControllers = junkViewControllers
   }
   }
   ```

What is good to know is that all views that a tabBarController contains is stored as an array in *tabBarController.viewControllers*.

This code basically creates an array called *junkViewControllers*. The for-loop then adds the existing UIViewControllers from the program in the order from the previous stored variables, based on the UIViewControllers' tags. When all this is done, the tabBarController shortened to *tabBar* is overwritten with the array *junkViewController*.

Answer (score 2):

This is what did the trick for me, building on the answers from Rickard & Jesper. All of the code goes into the main TabBarController.

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

let tabOrderKey = "customTabBarOrder"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    loadCustomTabOrder()
}

func loadCustomTabOrder() {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let standardOrderChanged = defaults.boolForKey(tabOrderKey)

    if standardOrderChanged {
        print("Standard Order has changed")

        var VCArray = [UIViewController]()
        var tagNumber = 0

        let tabBar = self as UITabBarController

        if let countVC = tabBar.viewControllers?.count {
            print("\(countVC) VCs in total")
            for var x = 0; x < countVC; x++ {
                tagNumber = defaults.integerForKey("tabPosition\(x)")

                for VC in tabBar.viewControllers! {
                    if tagNumber == VC.tabBarItem.tag {
                        VCArray.append(VC)
                        print("Position \(x): \(VCArray[x].tabBarItem.title!) VC (tag \(tagNumber))")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        tabBar.viewControllers = VCArray
    }

}

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didEndCustomizingViewControllers viewControllers: [UIViewController], changed: Bool) {

    print("Change func called")

    if changed {
        print("Order has changed")
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        for var x = 0; x < viewControllers.count; x++ {
            defaults.setInteger(viewControllers[x].tabBarItem.tag, forKey: "tabPosition\(x)")
            print("\(viewControllers[x].tabBarItem.title!) VC (with tag: \(viewControllers[x].tabBarItem.tag)) is now in position \(x)")
        }
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: tabOrderKey)
    } else {
        print("Nothing has changed")
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will explain how to do this programmatically. NOTE: This is using ARC, so you may have to insert retain/release calls as needed.

You use the `tag` property of the `UITabBarItem` for sorting.  For every `UIViewController` that you are adding to the `UITabBarController`, make sure that each has a unique `tag`.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.tabBarItem.tag = 0;
        self.tabBarItem.image = <image>;
        self.tabBarItem.title = <title>;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Presumably you would just use their default sorting order for their tags, so whatever you have as your original first view controller would be 0, followed by 1, 2, 3, etc.

Set up your UIViewControllers in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as you normally would, making sure that you are instantiating them in their "default order".  As you do so, add them to an instance of a NSMutableArray.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

    NSMutableArray *unsortedControllers = [NSMutableArray array];

    UIViewController *viewOne = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [unsortedControllers addObject:viewOne];

    UIViewController *viewTwo = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [unsortedControllers addObject:viewTwo];
    ...
```

After they are all instantiated and added to the array, you will check to see if the user has customized their order by querying `NSUserDefaults`.  In the defaults, you will store an array of the user's customized tab bar order.  This will be an array of NSNumbers (how this is created is explain in the last code snippet).  Use these to create a new "sorted" array of view controllers and pass that to the tab bar controller.  If they haven't customized the order, the default will return nil and you can simply used the unsorted array.

```
    ...
    NSArray *tabBarOrder = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"tabBarOrder"];
    if (tabBarOrder)
    {
      NSMutableArray *sortedControllers = [NSMutableArray array];
      for (NSNumber *sortNumber in tabBarOrder)
      {
         [sortedControllers addObject:[unsortedControllers objectAtIndex:[sortNumber intValue]]];
      }
      self.tabBarController.viewControllers = sortedControllers;
    } else {
      self.tabBarController.viewControllers = unsortedControllers;
    }
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

To create to customized sort order, use the UITabBarController's delegate method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didEndCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers changed:(BOOL)changed
{
    NSMutableArray *tabOrderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (UIViewController *vc in self.tabBarController.viewControllers)
    {
        [tabOrderArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[vc tabBarItem] tag]]];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:tabOrderArray] forKey:@"tabBarOrder"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: I did the Swift equivalent of this answer and it worked brilliantly. Only meaningful change I made was to use the parameter `viewControllers` that was already passed into `tabBarController:didEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:` and actually checked for `changed` before executing the saving of the New World Order™.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified Rickard Elimää answer even further. "Swift" solution to saving and loading Customized ViewControllers using the delegate function of tabBarController CustomizingViewControllers.

This is how I did it.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    let kOrder = "customOrder"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self

        loadCustomizedViews()
    }

    func loadCustomizedViews(){
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        // returns 0 if not set, hence having the tabItem's tags starting at 1.
        let changed : Bool = defaults.boolForKey(kOrder)

        if changed {
            var customViewControllers = [UIViewController]()
            var tagNumber: Int = 0
            for (var i=0; i<self.viewControllers?.count; i++) {
                // the tags are between 0-6 and the
                // viewControllers in the array are between 0-6
                // so we swap them to match the custom order
                tagNumber = defaults.integerForKey( String(i) )

                //print("TabBar re arrange i = \(i), tagNumber = \(tagNumber),  viewControllers.count = \(self.viewControllers?.count) ")
                customViewControllers.append(self.viewControllers![tagNumber])
            }

            self.viewControllers = customViewControllers
        }
    }

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didEndCustomizingViewControllers viewControllers: [UIViewController], changed: Bool){

        if (changed) {
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            //print("New tab order:")
            for (var i=0; i<viewControllers.count; i++) {
                defaults.setInteger(viewControllers[i].tabBarItem.tag, forKey: String(i))
                //print("\(i): \(viewControllers[i].tabBarItem.title!) (\(viewControllers[i].tabBarItem.tag))")
            }

            defaults.setBool(changed, forKey: kOrder)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer for Swift 2.0

`
    let tabBarOrderKey = "tabBarOrderKey"

```
extension TabBarButtonsController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

 // Saves new tab bar custom order

  func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didEndCustomizingViewControllers viewControllers: [UIViewController], changed: Bool) {
var orderedTagItems = [Int]()
if changed {
  for viewController in viewControllers {
    let tag = viewController.tabBarItem.tag
    orderedTagItems.append(tag)

  }
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(orderedTagItems, forKey: tabBarOrderKey)
}
}

// set up tag to compare with when pulling from defaults and for saving initial tab bar change

func setUpTabBarItemTags() {
var tag = 0
if let viewControllers = viewControllers {
  for view in viewControllers {
    view.tabBarItem.tag = tag
    tag += 1
  }
 }
}

// Get Saved Tab Bar Order from defaults

func getSavedTabBarItemsOrder() {
var newViewControllerOrder = [UIViewController]()
if let initialViewControllers = viewControllers {
  if let tabBarOrder = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(tabBarOrderKey) as? [Int] {
    for tag in tabBarOrder {
      newViewControllerOrder.append(initialViewControllers[tag])
    }
    setViewControllers(newViewControllerOrder, animated: false)
  }
 }
}
```

}

`

Remember to set the delegate and call these methods in the view did load

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share the code I have been working on for nearly 3 days now trying all sorts of combinations with many errors and failure - the general life of coding! ha ha.  Anyway the code below works with Swift 5.
 It's the extraction of [How to: Save order of tabs when customizing tabs in UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034183/how-to-save-order-of-tabs-when-customizing-tabs-in-uitabbarcontroller)  ,  Sam's Code, but with the for loop update for Swift 5.
I have got this working great, all in the TabBarViewController.swift file.

So if you just paste this into your Swift file, make sure your Tab Bar Items have a tag number from the Attributes Inspector and your good to go!

Thanks again to Sam for the Code in the first place.

```
import UIKit


class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

let tabOrderKey = "customTabBarOrder"

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.delegate = self
loadCustomTabOrder()
}

func loadCustomTabOrder() {

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let standardOrderChanged = defaults.bool(forKey: tabOrderKey)

if standardOrderChanged {
    print("Standard Order has changed")

    var VCArray = [UIViewController]()
    var tagNumber = 0

    let tabBar = self as UITabBarController

    if let countVC = tabBar.viewControllers?.count {
        print("\(countVC) VCs in total")
        for x in 0..<countVC {
            tagNumber = defaults.integer(forKey: "tabPosition\(x)")

            for VC in tabBar.viewControllers! {
                if tagNumber == VC.tabBarItem.tag {
                    VCArray.append(VC)
                    print("Position \(x): \(VCArray[x].tabBarItem.title!) VC (tag \(tagNumber))")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    tabBar.viewControllers = VCArray
 }

 }

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didEndCustomizing viewControllers: [UIViewController], changed: Bool) {

print("Change func called")

if changed {
    print("Order has changed")
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    for x in 0..<(viewControllers.count)  {
        defaults.set(viewControllers[x].tabBarItem.tag, forKey: "tabPosition\(x)")
        print("\(viewControllers[x].tabBarItem.title!) VC (with tag: \(viewControllers[x].tabBarItem.tag)) is now in position \(x)")
   }
    defaults.set(true, forKey: tabOrderKey)
    } else {
    print("Nothing has changed")
    }
  }

}
```