# xcode 4: How to save user changes from more tab bar

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, tabbar, savechanges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to: Save order of tabs when customizing tabs in UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034183/how-to-save-order-of-tabs-when-customizing-tabs-in-uitabbarcontroller)

I want to make it so that when on a tab bar application, if someone changes the order of the bottom tabs(e.g. move one from the 'more' section to the main section along the bottom) that the change saves and when you close and reopen the app they are as the user put them.

I dont even have any code to show you from where I am because none of the code so far even attempts this as I don't have a clue how to. I am very basic at programming(I'm only 15) so detailed instructions would be much appreciated! :)

Thanks!

Comment: This answer is probably what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034183/how-to-save-order-of-tabs-when-customizing-tabs-in-uitabbarcontroller

Comment: but I don't understand that, as previously mentioned, I'm very basic at programming :/ could you simply(e.g.explain what values need to be placed where?