# Saving the order of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to save the new tab orders generated when the user edits the UITabBar with the "More"->"edit" button present by default (app has more than 5 tab bar items). I'm using storyboard and no xib/nib files. The view controllers are linked up by using the storyboard and relationship segues

I set the TabBarController's custom class and add set the delegates for self.tabBarController and self.tabBar as self.
Unfortunately the order isn't saved after I close the app.
The `NSLog` messages are printed out so I know that the code is entering the functions shown below

Here's the code for saving/reading the order that I'm using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.delegate=self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"tabOrder"];
     NSArray* tabBarItems=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
     if (tabBarItems)
     {
         [self.tabBarController.tabBar setItems:tabBarItems animated:YES];
         NSLog(@"Loading changed Order%@",tabBarItems);
     }
}

-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didEndCustomizingItems:(NSArray *)items changed:(BOOL)changed
{
    NSLog(@"tab bar customizer");
    if (changed)
    {
        NSLog(@"order was changed");
        NSData *dataSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:items];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataSave forKey:@"tabOrder"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.tabBarController.viewControllers);
        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:items animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just like this [custom tabbar order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034183/how-to-save-order-of-tabs-when-customizing-tabs-in-uitabbarcontroller), you should store the viewController tag, not the object self. Because the UI instance has the some data that could not be store in NSData. You have to save the new order by the viewcontroller tag, then in your next time to open app just recover the new order by set the tabbar controller viewcontrollers.

Comment: Here is the problem i end up with when i try that approach:
1. I'm not using separate nib/xib files but storyboard instead  
2. self.tabBarController.viewControllers remains empty even upon editing the order  
3. the program doesn't enter the `- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didEndCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers changed:(BOOL)changed {}` functions after the editing is over.  
4. I'm unable to reference to the tabBarController from the app delegate.h/.m files