# TabBarController select by title?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

My app is tab based app, and it has 8 tabs. So it has button "more"
 where user can reorder tabs.

But in some ViewController, when user click on button, i need to go to another tab. I used this code:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

But if user reorder tabs, it will go to incorrect tab.

Comment: => here is post i hopes it is helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034183/how-to-save-order-of-tabs-when-customizing-tabs-in-uitabbarcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to check for Index of view controller or view controller at index.

```
-(NSInteger)getIndexOfViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
{
    return [self.tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:vc];
}

-(UIViewController *)getViewControllerAtIndex:(NSInteger )index
{
    return [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
}
```