# define specific TabBarController that isn´t the initial VC in AppDelegate - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

In my App there is a TabBarController that ins´t the initial VC.
I wanted to save the new tab order when the user `didEndCustomizingViewControllers`. 
I found a recently asked question: [How to: Save order of tabs when customizing tabs in UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034183/how-to-save-order-of-tabs-when-customizing-tabs-in-uitabbarcontroller)

I used the code of Rickard Elimää which defines the TabBarController as the initial Controller in **AppDelegate** :

```
let tabBar: UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
```

For testing whether the code to save the order works I set the TabBarController as the initial Controller and it works.
But the UITabBarController should´t be the initial VC.
So my question is how to define that TabBarController, so that the code works.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to do this is to implement `UIViewControllerTransitionDelegate`. This will handle animation as well as passing the rootViewController. It's a tad more complicated than just passing the rootViewController (as I originally had done), but it was worth the time to switch to this in the long run.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/).

[www.raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113845/ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions) (an implementation example)