# How to save the order of tabs in the Tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

once I changed the order of the tab inside the app through the "More" tab, when I close and re-open the app again, the order is backed to default. Any ideas how to save the order? Here is my configuration in story board:

[image]

Comment: Apple has foundational documentation that describes how to save and restore the visual state of your app between launches.  Please read "https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW2 and add specific questions when you run into problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to: Save order of tabs when customizing tabs in UITabBarController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034183/how-to-save-order-of-tabs-when-customizing-tabs-in-uitabbarcontroller)

Comment: Just save the current index to `UserDefaults`, then when you relaunch, set the `selectedIndex` to the index you saved.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for trying to help. I did look at all the related post before posting. I just want to confirm if there are some parts I have missed in the code as I tried all methods and they don't work. Anyways, I have solved the problem. I have found a bug in Xcode which leads to my issue.